# Optional orElseGet method returns ArrayList rather then Set

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa, option-type

The following code throws:

> ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set`

```
Set<Atuacao> a = atuacoes.findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(email.toUpperCase(),idSistema)
    .orElseGet(TreeSet::new);
```

The method `findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil` returns correctly two items of type `Atuacao` in a `Set`, in an `Optional`. Why the `orElseGet` method is returning an `ArrayList`?

I'm using `Spring Data Jpa`.

**Added:**
Method `findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil` definition:

```
public Optional<Set<Atuacao>> findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(
    @Param("email") String email, @Param("idSistema") long idSistema);
```

**Added:**

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
    at br.mp.mpf.autoriza.service.AtuacaoService.findAtuacoes(AtuacaoService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.mp.mpf.autoriza.service.AtuacaoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7bced465.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at br.mp.mpf.autoriza.service.AtuacaoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$961ace5.findAtuacoes(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.mp.mpf.seguranca.SecurityConfiguration.lambda$0(SecurityConfiguration.java:123) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:120) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: Please attach full stack trace. `TreeSet` is an extension of `Set`.

Comment: see this `findBy` returns `ArrayList` not `Set` https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: The `findBy` returns `Optional<Set<Atuacao>>`.

Comment: show the method definition of this method `findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil` @HernãSaldanha

Comment: findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(email.toUpperCase(),idSistema) definitely returns an arraylist not a set

Comment: public Optional<Set<Atuacao>> findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(@Param("email") String email, @Param("idSistema") long idSistema);

Comment: The ClassCastException occurs at runtime, not at compile.

Comment: Your method *declares* to return an `Optional<Set<Atuacao>>`, but only the actual code will show what it really returns.

Comment: Why? Just return a `List` instead of an `Optional` if there is no result it will return an empty list. Generally `Optional` for a collection type doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is a mix of ideas of @PattySpringDev and @m-deinum.

1. The method findBy is now returning Set only;
2. The class `Atuacao` now implements `Comparable` (there was a Comparator at another piece of code, removed);

**The final code is:**

```
public Set<Atuacao> findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(@Param("email") String email, @Param("idSistema") long idSistema);
Set<Atuacao> a = Optional.of(atuacoes.findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(email.toUpperCase(),idSistema)).orElse(new TreeSet<Atuacao>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Either 'Atuacao' has to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or you need to provide a comparator when creating the TreeSet.

As mentioned in [SortedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

> All elements inserted into a sorted set must implement the Comparable
>   interface (or be accepted by the specified comparator). Furthermore,
>   all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) (or
>   comparator.compare(e1, e2)) must not throw a ClassCastException for
>   any elements e1 and e2 in the sorted set. Attempts to violate this
>   restriction will cause the offending method or constructor invocation
>   to throw a ClassCastException

Another option will be to use hashset as below.

```
 Set<Atuacao> a = atuacoes.findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(email.toUpperCase(),idSistema)
        .orElseGet(HashSet::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil` probably returns `Optional<ArrayLIst<Atuacao>>` therefore there is no way to return `Set` in such way.

If you use **Java 11**, you can transform `Optional` to `Stream` and use the advantage of its collectors:

```
Set<Atuacao> a = atuacoes.findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(email.toUpperCase(),idSistema)
    .stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

If you stick with **Java 8**, then wrap the `ArrayList` into `TreeSet`:

```
new TreeSet<>(
    findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil(email.toUpperCase(),idSistema)
        .orElse(new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: The method `findByEmailAndSistemaAndPerfil` returns `Optional<Set<Atuacao>>`. Please see the question update.

Comment: Have you looked at the result with a debugger or similar? Or are you trusting the return type specification with your statement that the method returns a `Set`?